# WOOCOMMERCE - Integrar com banco de dados

Tags: woocommerce, integração

Precisava integrar o Woocommerce com um banco de dados próprio (diferente da estrutura do wordpress) para integrar em um software ERP. Sei que tem a API REST, mas não tenho a menor idéia de como fazer isso, pesquisei mas não tive uma luz no fim do tunel. Se alguém puder colocar ai um exemplo de como seria uma integração de produto simples com um banco de dados com (nome, codigo, tipo, preco, estoque [apenas exemplo]).

Comment: pergunta muito ampla... vc não definiu o que é a "integração", o que é um "produto simples" pra vc, qual é o ERP, qual é o banco de dados. Pessoal tem que ajudar na elaboração das perquntas pra ser ajudado.... por isso que muitas perguntas aqui ficam sem respostas.

Comment: Se você não tem nem idéia de como usar uma API REST imagine como deve ser adaptar o woocommerce para seu próprio banco de dados....
Minha sugestão é que pesquise como funciona a API REST do wocommerce e use ela, acredite em mim, é o jeito mais facil...

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

O interessante é através da documentação deles, é você buscar as informações que são retornadas em Json. E no seu sistema que irá receber, fazer esse tratamento do Json alimentando uma classe por exemplo.
Depois você mapeia as informações do eCommerce com os dados do seu banco!
Sua pergunta é um pouco ampla, mas um conselho para sua situação seria seguindo os passos abaixo:

1 - Verificar e implementar uma classe para acessar a API 
2 - Tratar as informações de retorno que é em Json
3 - Mapear os dados do seu banco com o retorno da API
4 - O controle para salvar as informações você pode fazer por algum arquivo de configuração ou utilizando os WebHooks que a própria API disponibiliza!

Aqui segue o link da documentação que uso, no começo precisei ler várias vezes até que ficasse mais claro a forma de funcionamento entre meu sistema e o WooCommerce http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#introduction